# After upload, my page is referencing incorrect folders

Tags: html, css

I recently finished up a mock site for a project that looks perfect locally. However, when I uploaded it to my server and Github pages, none of the styling is added. I checked the console, and see this:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   /favicon.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

So, I checked the sources in DevTools, and see that in my "resources" directory," there are two folders that don't actually exist: CSS and CSS_reset. Well, "CSS" is there, but it's referenced in my HTML as "css," so that's breaking the styling. CSS_reset doesn't exist AT ALL. Here's a screenshot of my directory tree on my server:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2BvD.jpg

And here's the HTML referencing the CSS:

```css
<link href="./resources/CSS_reset/reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" />
  <link href="./resources/CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton%7COpen+Sans:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

And here's the link to Github:

https://github.com/pauljhollis/jumpstart

I've uploaded about 15 pages to this server and github, and have NEVER seen this happen before. I have no idea what's causing this, and have checked all through devtools, and removed/re-added the files on my own server several times. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Edit: Answered. Something changed my code and changed "css" to "CSS" and added "CSS_reset," which isn't even a directory on my computer. This didn't happen on my pc last night, but I'm working on a different one today. Super weird. Thanks for the help/suggestions. I didn't even notice this had happened.

Comment: I don't understand what you are struggling with. You've established that the directory is called `css` but the HTML is directing the browser at `CSS` and `CSS_reset`. Change the HTML.

Comment: I think the path on your href pointing to these files are incorrect. Therefore, they can not be found. That is why 404 is issued.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened, but between saving my code and uploading it, the reference got chagned from "./resources/css/style.css" and "reset.css" to ./resources/CSS/style.css" and "./resources/CSS_reset/reset.css." Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`<link href="../resources/CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Another method is to use a base tag...

`<base href="https://www.[yourwebsite].com/resources/" target="_blank">`

...then link to the resource accordingly:

`<link href="CSS/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Also, note the CSS directory. I would make sure that's how it's spelled on the server.  Some are case-sensitive, so if the dir was "css" and you called "CSS", it wouldn't find it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what happened, but between saving my code and uploading it, the reference got chagned from "./resources/css/style.css" and "reset.css" to ./resources/CSS/style.css" and "./resources/CSS_reset/reset.css." Very strange.